# MSSQL INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS into a table, then use in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, select

got a real puzzler messing with my mind, can anyone help?

I put all table column names into a table and grouped the column names by a template name.

The idea is I can select template_1 and only those column names appear to use in a Select statement e.g.

-- Template Table --
- table1 -

```
firstname, template_A
lastname, template_A
field3, template_B
location, template_A
```

It seems to be if you pull a column name from a table fields (string value), you can SELECT it as a column.

Where it gets tough is, as I have different templates, I need to select the correct template, then have those fields call a second table for the value e.g.

-- Data Table --
- table2 -

```
firstname, lastname, location
David, Smith, Glasgow
```

-- Template to Data Reference --
- table3 -

```
table1_field1_id, table2_field1_id
```

I tried creating a variable first then running the SQL, e.g.

```
SET @COLS = 'SELECT t1.field, (SELECT ' + t1.field + ' FROM t2)
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.field1_id = t3.field1_id
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.field1_id = t3.field1_id
WHERE t1.template = 'template_A'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @COLS
```

I'm trying to get an output like...

```
firstname, David
lastname, Smith
location, Glasgow
```

The tough part is that different templates need to load different columns

Comment: What you have already done seems pretty good. Where is the problem, do you receive an error/incorrect result?

Comment: `WHERE t1.template = 'template_A'` isn't going to work. You should also be parametrising and safely injecting your values. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: Hi George, the column (SELECT ' + t1.field + ' FROM t2) loads the column name as the value, instead of selecting it as a column, I end up with:-

firstname, firstname
lastname, firstname
location, location

Instead of:

firstname, David
lastname, Smith
location, Glasgow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any solution here will be very difficult to compact into a single statement, and avoiding some sort of looping structure will also be very difficult. Here's a solution that involves a cursor.

By the way, using an approach like this, `table3` is redundant. At least, I didn't end up needing it.

```
-- BEGIN TEST DATA

create table table1 (field varchar(max), template varchar(max))
insert into table1 select 'firstname', 'template_A'
insert into table1 select 'lastname', 'template_A'
insert into table1 select 'field3', 'template_B'
insert into table1 select 'location', 'template_A'

create table table2 (firstname varchar(max), lastname varchar(max), location varchar(max))
insert into table2 select 'David', 'Smith', 'Glasgow'
insert into table2 select 'John', 'Hancock', 'Dublin'

-- END TEST DATA

declare @sql nvarchar(max)                     -- Used with sp_executesql
declare @field varchar(max)                    -- Temp variable for cursor
declare @template varchar(max) = 'template_A'  -- Set template name here

-- Temp table for output
create table #tmp (field varchar(max), value varchar(max))

-- BEGIN CURSOR

declare template_assignment cursor for 
select field from table1 where template = @template

open template_assignment  
fetch next from template_assignment into @field  

while @@fetch_status = 0  
begin  
    set @sql = 'insert into #tmp (value) select ' + @field + ' from table2'

    exec sp_executesql @sql

    update #tmp set field = @field where field is null

    fetch next from template_assignment into @field 
end 

close template_assignment  
deallocate template_assignment

-- END CURSOR

select * from #tmp
```

Comment: Great thanks Robb, I never thought about using a cursor, I never tried to pull a column name I stored in a table, that's what caught me out, trying to generate different columns based on selected templates, lesson learned.

I would have thought of trying to call a column from the schema may have worked and using the selected column name in a string in the where clause e.g.

SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'GenerateRequest' AND COLUMN_NAME = cfn.ColumnName

Thanks again, this will fix my issue. All the best David.